# ZF2 doesn't have "vendor" folder

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've got a problem with my ZF2 installation.
When I downloaded Zend framework skeleton on GitHub as well as git bash, it doesn't include a "vendor" folder.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to run `composer install` or `composer update` which will create this folder based on `composer.json` or `composer.lock` depends on command that you execute

If you don't know what composer is and how to run it go to https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md